# Remove whitespace between navigation header and frametitle in Beamer

Tags: beamer, mini-frames, beamer-metropolis

This is my first post. Thanks for your help!

**Backgound:** I'm building a Beamer presentation using the metropolis theme (because it looks nice) and the miniframes outer (for the progress header).

**Problem:** There's a whitespace between the navigation header and the frametitle that I can't get rid of (on image below it is between "First Section" and "Research Question"

**Desired Solutions:** I'd be happy to get rid of the whitespace or fill it in with mDarkTeal.

My code and the third slide (the one with the whitespace) are below. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[10pt, compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis} % Use metropolis theme
\useoutertheme{miniframes} %Use miniframes outer

%text and background color for navigation bar
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=mDarkTeal, bg=mLightBrown}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size=\scriptsize, series=\bfseries}

%Title Page Info
\title{Thanks for Your Help}
\date{\today}
\author{Me}

%Slides
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{First Section}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Research Question}
    \begin{center} \Large{\textbf{Is this a good question?}} \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the whitespace add the open `subsection=false` to the miniframes theme:

```
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes} %Use miniframes outer
```

**Output:**

[image: metropolis_miniframes]

Answer (score 3):

Define the same color for the subsections:

```
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=mDarkTeal, bg=mLightBrown}
```

[image: mwe]